# How do on demand resources "leave the bundle" and arrive on apple servers?

Tags: ios, on-demand-resources

I'm looking into apples in demand resources and I'm confused about the actual flow.

My application has a file named "file1"
It has an on demand resource tag of "file1"
When I run the app and open the debugger for disk I can see that tag "file1" has a status of not downloaded.

My question is, how does this does this work?

When I build my app is file1 excluded from being built into the bundle and automatically uploaded to apple servers?

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your app in debug mode, the on-demand-resource asset packs will be built by Xcode, then an "Xcode Server" process will be started by Xcode to deliver the asset packs on demand of your app.

When you test your app using TestFlight, the asset packs are uploaded to the Apple TestFlight servers, and downloaded on-demand to your device.

You can also upload the asset packs to your own HTTPS server, and set the on-demand host to your server URL in the project configuration.